# Android - Load image from URL to ImageView while showing progress (without saving the image)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-progressbar

Please consider the following AsyncTask. It is meant to download an image from URL and save it to the device, while showing the progress via a horizontal ProgressBar. Right now I'm not using the variable "bitmap" at all (it remains null). There are two things I want be able to do:

1. Load the image from the URL into an ImageView without saving the actual file to my device (is this even possible?), and show a ProgressBar while doing so - one that actually **shows progress**, and is more than just an animated circle.
2. (For whomever knows about Picasso) Do the exact same thing using Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/). 
   Picasso does make everything easy and I can just use this line of code: `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(imageView);`
   However it would be nice if I can actually show the progress while doing so (once again, using a ProgressBar that actually shows progress).

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'd appreciate any feedback regarding the current code and how it could be improved (It is mostly followed by this YouTube tutorial, so I feel like I should be giving credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HDr9FdGIVg).

```
    private class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>{
    private int contentLength = -1;
    private URL downloadURL = null;
    private HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    private InputStream inputStream = null;
    private File file;
    private OutputStream outputStream = null;
    private int counter = 0;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        setProgressBarProgress(0);
        showProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String[] objects)
    {
        try
        {
            downloadURL = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)downloadURL.openConnection();
            contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Uri.parse(objects[0]).getLastPathSegment());
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int read = -1;

            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                counter += read;
                publishProgress(counter);
            };
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            Msg.log("Security Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Msg.log("Other Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            //Even if our attempt to download the image did not succeed,
            //we should still close the connection, and the streams.
            //Otherwise, we are potentially wasting the device's resources.
            if (connection!=null)
                connection.disconnect();

            try {inputStream.close();}
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            try {outputStream.close();}
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            try {outputStream.flush();}
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        int progress = (int)(((double)values[0]/contentLength)*100);
        setProgressBarProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        hideProgressBar();
        if (result != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add progress bar to Picasso library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184156/how-to-add-progress-bar-to-picasso-library)

Answer (score 0):

Picasso can't actually give you the downloading progress but you can give it a callback that is called when the image is done loading.

The mostly used approach is to show a progress bar/circle and hides it when the download is complete.

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184156/how-to-add-progress-bar-to-picasso-library)

Comment: What about my first question, then?
Can it be done in this method?