# How to set progress bar value indicating an image loading from local folder in Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-imageview

I am trying to use a horizontal progress bar 
in my Android app, my question is how to set its value depending on the updated loaded size of the image that comes from raw folder?

Comment: Im my code, I am using BitmapFactory, which relatively takes time, to set images. Help if you know how, please.

Answer (score 0):

[Square's Picasso image library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) includes a callback when an image is successfully loaded into the ImageView. It won't give you exact progress but you could display an indeterminate ProgresBar until onSuccess fires.

See this question:

[How to add progress bar to Picasso library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184156/how-to-add-progress-bar-to-picasso-library)